# Promise.allSettled typescript array inference

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, type-inference

I want Typescript to infer types on a filtered array.

I am filtering my results based on the status "rejected" or "fullfilled" (from Promise.allSettled).

For some reason, Typescript is not inferring my filtering results.
Here is a minimal example of what I am trying to achieve:

```js
type FullFilledResults = {
  status: 'fullfilled';
  value: any;
}

type RejectResults = {
  status: 'rejected';
  reason: string;
}

type Results = RejectResults | FullFilledResults

const results: Results[] = [{
  status: 'rejected',
  reason: 'err'
}, {
  status: 'fullfilled',
  value: {}
}]

// Type infer Results[] but I want FullFilledResults[]
const fullfilledResults = results.filter(v => v.status === 'fullfilled')

// Type infer Results[] but I want RejectedResults[]
const rejectedResults = results.filter(v => v.status === 'rejected')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use type predicates for this purpose

```
function assertFullfilled(item: Results): item is FullFilledResults {
    return item.status === 'fullfilled';
}

const fullfilledResults = results.filter(assertFullfilled); // FullFilledResults[]
```

Comment: Thx, there is no way typescript can inference the type here?

Comment: As far as I know, it's not possible with current version of TS. There are discussions on github similar to your question like [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20812).

Answer (score 17):

Following function is generic for any PromiseSettled

```
function assertFulfilled<T>(item: PromiseSettledResult<T>): item is PromiseFulfilledResult<T> {
   return item.status === 'fulfilled';
}
```

Comment: you can take it one step forward by using a partition function (e.g. by lodash). Then by something like "const [setteled, rejected] = _.partition(items, assertFulfilled);" ts can infer the types of both result lists.

Comment: Awesome, man. It exactly what i'm looking for about 4 hours